# GA Event Tracking - Double form submission event logged

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I have set up event tracking to track how many times the page is visited + how many times a modal trigger button is hit + How many times a form in the said modal is submitted.

Implemented tracking via GTM.

Now when I test with the GTM preview tool, events are reflecting fine but the form submission is displayed twice (with the event triggering for both) even tho form is submitted only once as intended.

Does this mean the GTM is logging 2 events for each submission or is having 2 occurrences in GTM preview a normal thing?

[Screenshot of the preview tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ByIi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not normal, it means that the event is sent 2 times.